# Can no longer access Hotmail account on Android device

Tags: hotmail, outlook.com

Since moving from Hotmail to Outlook, I can no longer access emails on my Android device. I have installed, removed, and reinstalled the Outlook app, but despite my receiving emails daily my inbox is blank.

How to use a Hotmail account on an Android device?

Comment: Did you try adding some other hotmail account? at least for the sake of checking? And is your emails on a custom domain or hotmail's generic domain?

Answer (score 0):

Usual solution is to remove and re-add the account, on your mobile Outlook.com.
Generally that works.
(Obviously you will lose any mails and unsent outgoing mails (manually save unsent outgoing mails first with some file-manager app, if you need them)).

Be warned: Outlook.com's Android sync is very brittle, and their support is nearly non-existent.
Beware of taking over-the-wire Android updates.

Comment: But where is the 'Outgoing' folder?